# text area cursor jumps to top when focus lost IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have a standard text area with a lot of content which shows overflow, when I lose focus on this text area by either clicking out or tabbing out of the text box the cursor within the text box jumps to the top.

Plus when I stop typing the same occurs

Is there any way to prevent this with jquery or another means? I am unsure if it is a bug in IE8 but this is a client request.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This would appear not to be standard behaviour. Do you have any events linked to the `blur` event for the textarea?

Comment: This is a recognised bug in IE8, and has been asked multiple times, for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933320/), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080270) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280247)

Comment: OK if it is a bug has there been a fix / patch

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of... plus are you going to require every single person who sees your page (assuming it's not an intranet) to install the patch? I will write an answer to give some helpers

Comment: Blimey @CR41G14, that was a quick "accepted answer tick"... what did you use to fix your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a recognised bug in IE8, but there is no patch/hotfix available that I'm aware of (plus, even if there was, there is no guarantee the computer viewing your page has the patch/hotfix in place).

This happens on textboxes which are using a percentage width, rather than fixed width, and there are several recorded "fixes", although not all worked for me...

Firstly there is the option of fixing the width of the textarea via CSS, but also using `min-width` and `max-width` to set the percentage (however, this isn't going to work in old browsers).  This could not work for me because the sheer number of textareas I use that all need different widths.

```
textarea {
  width: 700px;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

[Here is an article from somebody who originally found the bug, with an explanation of the above.](http://grantovich.net/misc/ie8-textarea-bug/)

Secondly, you could try setting the number of columns to be much, much larger than the visual size of the textbox.  [Here is an answer giving details of how to do this, and why they think this is the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933329/930393)  However, I couldn't actually get this to work, despite it being the accepted answer with several up-votes.

In the end I choose to force IE8 into using compatibility mode using the following `meta` tag at the very start of each page (I use ASP.NET master-pages, so this wasn't a big job).

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

This will also made the "compatibility" button disappear, so it's impossible for your users to accidentally put it back into IE8 mode.

Comment: This worked for me whereas Justin Grant's "cols" strategy did not.

Comment: I had to add a fixed height for the textarea to stop the erratic jumping.